# Is it possible to work with API centric programming while using ADF?

Tags: coding-style, oracle-adf

I am planning to use , ADF for my next project. It have couple of screens where , user enter data and that data is processed and stored in DB. 
By processing , what I mean is , like creating categories out of it and all kind of stuff . Even , planning to build a payment screens through ADF.

But the problem , I am facing is ADF is tightly coupled with idea of binding UI with EO/VO objects.

ie;  screen field is bind to VO attribute  and on button click of "Save" , it just commit the transaction.

Is it possible with ADF to build a layered architecture in a way that , not to update data directly from screen and provide clean APIs ?

Thanks
Jijoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use Business Components, you can use programmatic or read only View objects, to retrieve / keep your data, and to provide additional methods in your backing beans to do database talk.This way you can avoid Entity objects.
However, you can also override DML methods in Entity objects to provide your custom logic of talking with database,and you can continue to use all features of AM, VO and EOs without much effort.
Also, 
I suppose that your button "Save" is bound through action listener to a page definition. However if you need some additional work done, use right click and convert it to a method, and you'll get new method with already prepared code. Also if needed, you can remove existing logic and write your own

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can trap/listen for the button click and in the backing bean call ADF API methods by hand.